# Get data from current week and month in the Room Database

Tags: android, android-room

I'm trying to get data from current Week and Month in Room. I've created a current Day query and it works, but the others do not work.

Day query (this one works):

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM expense_table WHERE day = strftime('%d', 'now')")
LiveData<List<Expense>> getExpensesDay();
```

Week:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM expense_table WHERE week = strftime('%W', 'now')")
LiveData<List<Expense>> getExpensesWeek();
```

Month:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM expense_table WHERE month = strftime('%m', 'now')")
LiveData<List<Expense>> getExpensesMonth();
```

Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "expense_table")
public class Expense  {

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
private int expenseId;
private String note;
private Double value;
private String type;
private Long dateLong = System.currentTimeMillis();
private String date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/yyyy").format(new Date(dateLong));
private static Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
private int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
private int week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
private int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
private int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
private String weekDay = new DateFormatSymbols().getWeekdays()[dayOfWeek];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to docs, `strftime('%W', ...)` substitutes week of year with 0-based, and `Calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)` returns week of year with 1-based. Similarly,  `strftime('%m', ...)` substitutes week of year with 1-based, and  `Calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)` returns week of year with 0-based.

So, try to replace calculation of fields in your `Entity` class:

```
private int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
private int week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) - 1;
```

instead of

```
private int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
private int week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

Comment: It's so strange, but when I tried it for the first time it did not work, now it works. Maybe I had something wrong in my query? I don't know. Thank you for your help. Everything works now.